Unable to reach /{culture}/Error page when using RouteDataRequestCultureProvider
I have an Net8 webapp with request localization. When an error is throw, it fails to navigate to the Error page because it treats Error in the URL as Culture and tries to navigate to http://localhost:5245/Error/Index.
If I specify app.UseExceptionHandler("/en/Error") it is successful, but I can't serve the page in another language.
I've had some success writing a custom error handler, but I want to redirect the user to the Error page since the page nav are included rather than returning plain text or handcoding HTML.
Program.cs
using System.Globalization;
using LocalizationWithErrors.Conventions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var services = builder.Services;
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("en"),
        new CultureInfo("fr"),
    };
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(supportedCultures[0]);
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider() { Options = options });
});

services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new GlobalTemplatePageRouteModelConvention());
});

var app = builder.Build();

/*
It works if I include the language in the path to the 
ExceptionHandler page, but I'm not able to add the path for multiple supported languages
*/
// app.UseExceptionHandler("/en/Error");

app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

var localizationOptions = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value;

app.UseRouting();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();

RouteModelConvention:
This creates a route model convention for all pages in the app for each support culture.
en/Index, fr/index, en/Privacy, fr/Privacy, en/Error, fr/Error
I've tried excluding / including the Error page in the convention to see how it affected routing, but it does not see to have any effect.
GlobalTemplatePageRouteModelConvention.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels;

namespace LocalizationWithErrors.Conventions;
public class GlobalTemplatePageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        var selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count();
        if (!model.RelativePath.Contains("Error"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < selectorCount; i++)
            {
                SelectorModel selector = model.Selectors[i];
                model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
                {
                    AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                    {
                        Order = -1,
                        Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{culture}",
                            selector.AttributeRouteModel!.Template
                            ),
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}


Pages/Index.cshtml
@page
@using System.Globalization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
    var requestCultureFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>CultureInfo: @requestCultureFeature.RequestCulture.Culture</p>
    <p>CurrentUICulture: @requestCultureFeature.RequestCulture.UICulture</p>
</div>
<form method="POST">
    <button type="submit">Cause an error</button>
</form>

Pages/Index.cshtml.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace LocalizationWithErrors.Pages;
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
/* Throw an exception to trigger the Error handler */
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost() => throw new FileNotFoundException("Whoops");
}


Pages/Error.cshtml
@page
@model ErrorModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Error";
}

<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>

@if (Model.ShowRequestId)
{
    <p>
        <strong>Request ID:</strong> <code>@Model.RequestId</code>
    </p>
}

Pages/Error.cshtml.cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace LocalizationWithErrors.Pages;

[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public class ErrorModel : PageModel
{
    public string? RequestId { get; set; }
    public bool ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);

    public void OnGet() => RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
}

How can I include the culture in the route for the Error page?
EDIT 2024-04-09 22:40 (-5:00 GMT)
Per @Guru Stron's request, I have edited the post to include all the code required to recreate the issue.

Can you please add full [mre] solution so it would be easier to replicate/play with?

@GuruStron thank you, I've added the code which will hopefully allow you to replicate.

Indeed, I found that HttpContext clears the data after entering the Page.
I also tried HttpContext.Items, and failed, I found the workaround by using session. Here is the code.
MyCustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;

namespace WebRazorPage7._0
{
    public class MyCustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public MyCustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(httpContext);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var requestCultureFeature = httpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
                var culture = requestCultureFeature?.RequestCulture.Culture.Name ?? "en";

                httpContext.Session.SetString("ExceptionMessage", ex.Message);
                httpContext.Session.SetString("ExceptionStackTrace", ex.StackTrace);


                var errorUrl = $"/{culture}/Error";
                httpContext.Response.Redirect(errorUrl);
                //return;
            }
        }
    }
    public static class CustomExceptionHandlerMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<MyCustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
        }
    }

}

Program.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace WebRazorPage7._0
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            //builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
            var services = builder.Services;
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new[]
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en"),
                    new CultureInfo("fr"),
                };
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(supportedCultures[0]);
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider() { Options = options });
            });

            services.AddRazorPages(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.Add(new GlobalTemplatePageRouteModelConvention());
            });

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            var app = builder.Build();

            var localizationOptions = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value;
            
           
            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            //if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            //{
            //    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            //    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            //    app.UseHsts();
            //}
           
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

            app.UseCustomExceptionHandler();

            app.MapRazorPages();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}

fr/Error.cshtml
@page 
@model frErrorModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Error";
}

<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2>@Model.Message</h2>
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.StackTrace))
{
    <pre>@Model.StackTrace</pre>
}

fr/Error.cshtml.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WebRazorPage7._0.Pages.fr
{
    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public class ErrorModel(ILogger<ErrorModel> logger) : PageModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string StackTrace { get; set; }
        public string? RequestId { get; set; }

        public bool ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);

        private readonly ILogger<ErrorModel> _logger = logger;

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Message = HttpContext.Session.GetString("ExceptionMessage");
            StackTrace = HttpContext.Session.GetString("ExceptionStackTrace");
        }
    }

}

Test Result


Try to add a custom middleware like: MyCustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware, and register it.
MyCustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;

namespace culture_Error
{
    public class MyCustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public MyCustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(httpContext);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                var requestCultureFeature = httpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
                var culture = requestCultureFeature?.RequestCulture.Culture.Name ?? "en";

                var errorUrl = $"/{culture}/Error";

                httpContext.Response.Redirect(errorUrl);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class CustomExceptionHandlerMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<MyCustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
        }
    }

}

Register it

Test Result


This does handle the route, but the exception does not get passed to the Error page - it's cleared from the HttpContext.

@StevenBitaxi I have updated my answer, please kindly check it.
